# How to make clear that this site is not about maths?

Tags: discussion

This might sounds trivial to anyone familiar with Mathematica, the software, but to an unsuspecting user, this stack exchange looks like a very odd collection of maths related questions.

Could there be a way to point out, prefereably right on the front page, that this Q&A site is not about maths as such, but about a software called 'Mathematica'?

Comment: "prefereably right on the front page, that this Q&A site is not about maths as such, but about a software called 'Mathematica'?" - doesn't the big *"Mathematica"* logo give it away?

Comment: My point exactly. Many users will stumble over this site while searching for maths related answers and will not know that it is a logo - personally, I thought the icon to look rather nice, but was not aware this is some software.

Comment: perhaps even using the well-known spikey would not have been enough to make it clear to the unaware that this isn't a site about mathematica, but about Mathematica(R).

Comment: You are right it confuses a lot of people. We regularly delete and/or migrate math questions that have been posted here by mistake. The name of the site doesn't help but is IMO essential. One ugly way out might be to call it WRI's Mathematica or something similar, but that may confuse a lot of people too (for instance in thinking this is a Wolfram owned site).

Comment: Personally, I thought the circled R indicating that _Mathematica_ was a registered trademark gave it away. But, I suspect we will have to live with the confusion.

Comment: Renaming the site is the only option. Wolfram calls Mathematica, Wolfram Mathematica. That would alert some that its not about mathematics. Renaming to Wolfram Mathematica Development Platform would do the trick.

Comment: @ndroock1 - WRI might object. We wanted to call http://electronics.stackexchange.com "Electronic Design" but got a cease and desist from the magazine with the same name because of trademark infringement. WRI accepts using the name "Mathematica" because it's unavoidable and good publicity, but WRI is not associated with SE.

Comment: @ndroock1 I agree with stevenvh and Sjoerd. Just want to add that the more we will be independent of WRI the better it will be for us, for WRI, and for Mathematica. The use of Mathematica is anyway crippled by the critique of its proprietary nature by open source proponents (which, IMO, is both valid and not at the same time), and this site will attract much more current and potential Mathematica users by being explicitly and manifestly objective, open  and community-driven. The name you sugested sounds very much like the name of a site officially supported, controlled or even owned by WRI.

Comment: " The use of Mathematica is anyway crippled by the critique of its proprietary nature. " I doubt that's the ( main ) reason. Oracle is proprietary, and the entire Apple ecosystem is proprietary. Both have huge, cult-like followings.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you start a new question this panel pops up at the right:

[image]

I'm not sure everybody will read this, but since it's there anyway, we might change the question in bold into

> **Is your question about the
>
>   Mathematica® technical
>
>   computing software ?**

Comment: Sounds like a possible change that is neither to intrusive but makes the point. This, however, will not affect users only browsing the site.

Comment: @kontur I think anyone just browsing the site will figure out in 5 mins that this is not a site about mathematics. It's the ones that ask questions mistakenly, hence necessitating cleanup/closing/migrating etc., that we need to optimize for. I like steven's solution for this that might help clarify for a few users.

Comment: True that, I agree.

Answer (score 7):

And why not have a capital "M"? :)

[image: picture]

Comment: "Don't ask about Maths!"

Comment: I guess Mathematica should be capitalized and italicized there.

Comment: @rcollyer We had this problem in StackOverflow for eons. Users kept reading _Mathematics_ instead of _Mathematica_. I am hopeless about this kind of solutions. "Don't ask about Math" or similar is the only way to go

Comment: @verde I recall, vividly. But, I was more referring to the fact that looks like a bug in the interface.

Comment: @rcollyer hehe. We are lucky to be powerless. [This kind of misunderstandings between others had sparkled wars](http://tpmlivewire.talkingpointsmemo.com/2010/02/palin-advocates-war-with-iran-after-misunderstanding-buchanan-column.php)

Answer (score 3):

`If[rep < 10, Show["this"], smile, suggestRegistering]`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

Other possible messages (add your own):

- "About to post a Math question? Don't!" (acl)
- "Have a Maths related question? Ask in [the Mathematics site](http://math.stackexchange.com)
- "Only ask questions about the Mathematica technical software" (stevenvh)

Comment: "about to post a math question? Don't!"

Comment: @acl My point is that casual users will not read small or off-line-of-sight text. To deliver the message efficiently, you need to force them to focus in it by being **obtrusive**.

Comment: If I were to make a point here it would be this: if someone posts a question here without realising it's not called Mathematics, then they've put so little effort into the whole thing that the question is almost certainly not worth keeping or answering. However, I'm not actually making this point as we're all nice around here

Comment: In my communication courses I've always learned never to say what it's not. Say what it *is*.

Comment: @stevenvh [Sure?](http://us.123rf.com/400wm/400/400/fintastique/fintastique0802/fintastique080200087/2497143-park-rules-no-cycling-skating-littering-skate-boards.jpg)

Comment: @Verde - Those skipped class! :-) The reason is that you can't list up everything you want to exclude, the list is endless. You don't want math, Matlab, Chaco,... Are you going to mention them all? Just say "Only Mathematica"

Comment: @stevenvh [Ruling by negatives organized humanity (for good or bad) during quite a few years](http://ancienthistory.about.com/od/monotheisticreligions/tp/052308tencommandments.htm), while the positive enunciates and explications are [prone to misunderstanding](https://i.chzbgr.com/completestore/12/8/16/NV-IBKwRBUmjha06ZPwaOQ2.jpg)

Comment: @Verde - To the point: "Only ask questions about the Mathematica technical software" shouldn't lead to misunderstandings IMO, and it rules out everything else, including math and Matlab, without having to list them up. If you still have to add "No math" I'd call it stubbornness.