# Opening a migration path to math.SE?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, migration

After the fifth or so question that should have been posted to math.SE instead of here in the past few days, I must ask: should we petition for opening a migration path to math.SE? Those five questions were lucky that I caught them; still, it would be nice if there was a way for users with voting privileges to be able to do the migration themselves...

Thus far, I see from the mod panel that 28 questions (out of 47) that were mistakenly asked at the main site have been migrated to math.SE.

What do you guys think?

([Here](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/617) is a related discussion.)

Comment: I think you could rephrase your question so that an upvote means clearly "yes, open it".

Comment: "yes, open it".

Comment: @bel, maybe one of us could post a "poll answer" instead...

Comment: I don't think a poll is necessary... this is really a no-brainer from our end, and I think we all would like this migration path (but not from math.se). Now, if SE will listen...

Comment: @rm, [speaking of SE's responsiveness...](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3853) yeesh.

Comment: @J.M. Bumped it good :)

Comment: A poll is unnecessary. It's more the upvotes on the question as well as the migration history (I counted 29 migrations but I may or may not have double counted one). 21 in the last 90 days.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[image: Image of the new close dialogue that now includes a path to Maths]

A random question, namely the topmost on the front page at the time of taking the picture, was selected as the model for this screenshot.

And there y'go! In review of the current volume and the frequency, as well as thoughts expressed now and then from the community, we have decided to instate this direction of a migrational path. Thanks to Shog9 for instating the actual path.

Comment: ...and just when I stopped believing in wishing wells. Thanks, Shog and Grace!